# get average elapsed time for each month

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table that has entry date and completion date on it (records go back a couple years) and i need to write a query that gives the average amount of time completion takes by each month. I can get the overall average,

```
SELECT AVG ( t.completion_dt - t.entry_dt ) * 24 
  FROM table t;
```

or the average for a *specific month*,

```
SELECT AVG ( t.completion_dt - t.entry_dt ) * 24 
  FROM table t
 WHERE t.entry_dt BETWEEN to_date('2018/12/01','yyyy/mm/dd') AND
                          to_date('2019/1/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Is there a way to get the query to return the average for each month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are wanting to see each month/year independently (Jan 2020 on a different row from Jan 2019), then you can group on your `entry_dt` field truncated at the month.

```
SELECT trunc(t.entry_dt,'MM'),
       AVG ( t.completion_dt - t.entry_dt ) * 24 
  FROM table t
group by trunc(t.entry_dt,'MM');
```

If you are wanting to average ALL January months together across multiple years, you will want to group on something like the to_char of your `entry_dt` field.

```
SELECT to_char(t.entry_dt, 'Month'),
       AVG ( t.completion_dt - t.entry_dt ) * 24 
  FROM table t
group by to_char(t.entry_dt, 'Month');
```